# Can a phrase like "being honest" be considered a verb?

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

If I have a sentence like "I was talking with her", "talking" is clearly the verb, right?

If I construct a similar sentence, "I was being honest with her", is "being honest", as a phrase, a verb? Is there a way to consider those two words taken together as a verb? Is it a "phrasal verb"?

"Being honest" seems like it behaves like a verb to me - it takes the place of a verb and seems to act in every grammatical way like a verb, by my estimation, but I'm not confident.

Comment: Does *being dishonest* feel like a verb to you? How about *being coy*?  or *being less than forthcoming*?

Comment: In practice, there's not really much difference between *I was honest* and *I was being honest*. See [this earlier question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68709/should-i-use-the-present-simple-or-continuous-to-say-that-a-word-is-being-used) about ***X is used*** and ***X is being used***.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Verbs are words, not phrases.

In "I was talking with her" there are two verbs "was" and "talking".  The verb "talking" heads a subordinate participle clause to the matrix clause "I was {...}", This is called a progressive, or continuous construction.

In "I was being honest with her", the matrix clause is "I was {...}" and the subordinate clause is "being honest with her".  It is headed by a participle verb "being" and honest is an adjective, a required complement of the verb. This is another progressive or "past continuous" tense.

In both cases "with her" is a prepositional phrase. It is supplementary. It adds more information, but isn't grammatically required.

Comment: While this is the right answer for this application, I would argue that ["phrasal verbs" are a thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phrasal_verbs), at least as a useful concept for learners. Partly just because certain phrasal combinations have meanings that are distinct from the sum of their parts. "You set me up," "you put me down."

Comment: Yes, I'd agree, @Andy and we should be careful about what "word" means.  It isn't necessarily defined by the written form.  But this isn't a phrasal verb.